# Undefined reference to pcl_ros::transformPointCloud

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am migrating to catkin and I am trying to compile a node already compiled under rosbuild.
I have this message error: `undefined reference to pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(std::string const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, tf::TransformListener const&)`

I followed the migration guide.
This is the CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(path_planner)   

find_package(catkin REQUIRED 
    COMPONENTS 
    dynamic_reconfigure
    pcl_conversions
        roscpp
    tf
    rospy
    geometry_msgs 
    interactive_markers

)
find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME} 
  CATKIN_DEPENDS 
    geometry_msgs 
    pcl_conversions 
    roscpp 
    rospy 
    tf 
    std_msgs
    pcl_ros
    interactive_markers
  DEPENDS PCL 
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   
 add_library(normalestimation src/NormalEstimationPcl.cpp)
 add_library(dynamicjoinpcl src/DynamicJoinPcl.cpp)
 add_library(clusterpcl src/ClusterPcl.cpp)
 add_library(conversionpcl src/ConversionPcl.cpp)
 add_library(travanalpcl src/TravAnal.cpp)
 add_library(pathplanning src/PathPlanning.cpp)
 add_library(marker src/MarkerController.cpp)
    
add_executable(mapping src/mapping.cpp)
add_executable(traversability src/traversability.cpp)
add_executable(pathPlanner src/pathPlanner.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mapping dynamicjoinpcl  conversionpcl normalestimation  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(traversability clusterpcl  conversionpcl travanalpcl  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(pathPlanner marker  pathplanning   ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
 
install(FILES
    launch/test.launch
    launch/test.yaml   
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
 )
```

And this is the package.xml

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
 
<build_depend>message_runtime</build_depend>   <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>  
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>  
<build_depend>dynamic_reconfigure</build_depend>
<build_depend>tf</build_depend>  
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend> 
<build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>visualization_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>  
<build_depend>pcl_conversions</build_depend>   <build_depend>interactive_markers</build_depend>
<build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend> 
<build_depend>laser_geometry</build_depend>
<build_depend>dynamic_reconfigure</build_depend>
<build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>  

<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>  
<run_depend>rospy</run_depend>  
<run_depend>dynamic_reconfigure</run_depend>
<run_depend>tf</run_depend>  
<run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>  
<run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>visualization_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>libpcl-all</run_depend>  
<run_depend>pcl_conversions</run_depend>
<run_depend>interactive_markers</run_depend>
<run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>  
<run_depend>laser_geometry</run_depend>
<run_depend>dynamic_reconfigure</run_depend>
<run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>

<test_depend>python-mock</test_depend>
```

What I forget????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198460/undefined-reference-to-pcl_ros::transformpointcloud/) by [mennamatteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20961/mennamatteo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also had a linking problem with `pcl_ros::transformPointCloud()` and solved it by changing the point type from `PointXY` to `PointXYZ` (`pcl_ros::transformPointCloud()` can only cope with 3d-points).

**Edit:**
Try `#include <pcl_ros/impl/transfoms.hpp>`. This solved the linker error and gave me more helpful compiler errors instead (complaining about the missing 'z'). Though your problem seems to be different, it might give you a more helpful error, too.

---

Originally posted by [luator](https://answers.ros.org/users/21035/luator/) with karma: 108 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mennamatteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20961/mennamatteo/) on 2014-12-05**:
In my case it can be both PointXYZ and PointXYZRGBNormal

**Comment by [luator](https://answers.ros.org/users/21035/luator/) on 2014-12-05**:
@mennamatteo: They should both be ok, my problem was the missing Z. Maybe try `#include <pcl_ros/impl/transfoms.hpp>`, see edit.

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2016-06-01**:
`#include <pcl_ros/impl/transforms.hpp>` helped me too (I have a custom point type). I think the function needs to be re-compiles for custom point types and is pre-compiled for the standard ones ..?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-pcl-ros
sudo apt install ros-melodic-pcl-conversions
```

works.
ubuntu 18.04.3 . ROS melodic .
This is my CMakeLists.txt for you reference
Wrap up opencv(v3.2)  gtSAM PCL(1.8)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(icp)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -Wall -g -pthread")


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation
  nav_msgs
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  tf
)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED QUIET)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED QUIET)
find_package(GTSAM REQUIRED QUIET)

add_message_files(
  DIRECTORY msg
  FILES
  cloud_info.msg
)


generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  geometry_msgs
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  DEPENDS PCL GTSAM

  CATKIN_DEPENDS 
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  pcl_conversions
  sensor_msgs
  message_runtime 
  message_generation
)

# include directories
include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GTSAM_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

# link directories
link_directories(
    include
    ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${GTSAM_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_icp_localization src/icp_localization.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_icp_localization ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} gtsam)
```

---

Originally posted by [schwarmcyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/26007/schwarmcyc/) with karma: 36 on 2020-11-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schwarmcyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/26007/schwarmcyc/) on 2020-11-27**:
And if you wonder why

```
undefined reference to `void pcl_ros::transformPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&, tf::Transform const&)'
```

means cannot find .so  linking PCL to ROS that function share objects.